# Should I fill nail holes in a roof deck before installing underlayment?

Tags: roof

I'm getting ready to install roofing shingles on an outdoor shed/office. The roof has a small/moderate incline.  At the moment, the roof just has bare plywood on it.  In several spots, I needed to remove/relocate nails so there are some old holes in the roof deck.  Should I fill these in with something? If so, what compound should I use to fill in the holes?

Or is that not necessary considering that I'm going to place underlayment felt over everything and shingles over that?

Comment: What is the "small/moderate incline"? Shingles get tricky below 3 in 12 slope. Other products may be a better choice if it's something like a 1 in 12 slope.

Answer (score 3):

Correct; no need to waste time filling them in. The underlayment and roofing materials themselves act as the waterproofing. The nails for the shingles are going to penetrate the roof deck anyway.

Answer (score 2):

NAIL holes - not an issue. Larger holes should be patched, unsound plywood should be replaced with sound plywood, etc.